# Extended Gaussian Image

Tags: algorithm, math, gaussian

I'm trying to write an algorithm to align 3d models. The method I have chosen is the **Extended Gaussian images** (needle maps or depth maps) based on the article published by Mr. Horn[[1](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1457341&isnumber=31344)].

I'm *fighting against time* in this implementation so my question is if anybody knows any implementation I can re-use?

Or, regarding the topic of *3D Model Alignment*,  anyone suggest another method?

---

Reference:

[1] - Horn, B.K.P.; , "Extended Gaussian images," Proceedings of the IEEE , vol.72, no.12, pp. 1671- 1686, Dec. 1984
doi: 10.1109/PROC.1984.13073
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1457341&isnumber=31344

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do sounds like point cloud registration.

You might try using the point cloud library (PCL): http://www.pointclouds.org/